# GLFW - Failed To Open A Window

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, glfw, unresolved-external

As my hunt for a cross-platform framework/library went in progress, GLFW was mentioned many times. So, I decided to try it out. Now, it seems as though I can't even init a window. :-/

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <gl/glfw.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int running = GL_TRUE;
    srand(time(NULL));

    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    if (!glfwOpenWindow(300, 300, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GLFW_WINDOW))
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (running)
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glClearColor(rand() % 255 + 1, rand() % 255 + 1, rand() % 255 + 1, 0);

        glfwSwapBuffers();

        running = !glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_ESC) && glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED);
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I typed this in MVC++ 2010, linked the header, and 2 lib files (and it had 1 DLL file, so I threw that into the SysWOW64 folder), and I get these errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: glfwTest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1> test.cpp
1>c:\users\andrew\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\glfwtest\glfwtest\test.cpp(8): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\andrew\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\glfwtest\glfwtest\test.cpp(22): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'int' to 'GLclampf', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\andrew\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\glfwtest\glfwtest\test.cpp(22): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'int' to 'GLclampf', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\andrew\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\glfwtest\glfwtest\test.cpp(22): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'int' to 'GLclampf', possible loss of data
1>test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClearColor@16 referenced in function _main
1>GLFW.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClearColor@16
1>test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClear@4 referenced in function _main
1>GLFW.lib(window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClear@4
1>GLFW.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClear@4
1>GLFW.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglGetProcAddress@4 referenced in function _initWGLExtensions
1>GLFW.lib(win32_glext.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglGetProcAddress@4
1>GLFW.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglMakeCurrent@8 referenced in function _createWindow
1>GLFW.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglCreateContext@4 referenced in function _createContext
1>GLFW.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglDeleteContext@4 referenced in function _destroyWindow
1>GLFW.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glGetFloatv@8 referenced in function __glfwPlatformSetWindowSize
1>GLFW.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glGetIntegerv@8 referenced in function __glfwPlatformSetWindowSize
1>GLFW.lib(glext.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glGetIntegerv@8
1>GLFW.lib(glext.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glGetString@4 referenced in function __glfwParseGLVersion
1>c:\users\andrew\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\glfwTest\Debug\glfwTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 9 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I understand the first few with the random colors, but the ones after that make no sense to me. Any idea what's wrong with this?

I'm pretty sure that I have linked the libs correctly. I place them into the
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib directory
and even linked them to my
C:\SDK\GLFW\glfw-2.7.bin.WIN32\lib-msvc100\debug directory.

The GLFW package was a .zip file, so I just extracted it to my default SDK folder (for all my APIs and other stuff). So the C:\SDK\GLFW is my default for GLFW.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You need to link to `opengl32.lib`.

For that, as pictured below, go to `Project Setting` and then `Linker > input > Additional Dependencies` and add `opengl32.lib` there (use `;` to separate different libs).

Note that you don't actually need to have `opengl32.lib` file anywhere. Visual Studio knows where to find it.

[image: Linking to extra libs in Visual Studio]

Edit: I should note that you don't need to do anything except adding `opengl32.lib`. That other stuff is irrelevant. Additionally, if both are present, try swapping the order, which matters in some cases.

Comment: link to opengl32.lib except with opengl32.lib? It's the same thing. :P But thanks! It worked now! :D

Comment: Oh, no - I was referring to the picture when I said that. I put the picture up as a demonstration, but since I don't have VS on this computer I couldn't take a screenshot myself.

Comment: To everyone still fustrated as hell and new to c++ like me. opengl32.lib doesnt need to be located in your library folder you refrenced, (if you have SDK installed that is... which you properbly have)

Comment: @JohnChadwick, This really helped me! Thanks a lot to point it out :)